# Can someone please explain the flex-basis property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know that it works "hand in hand the flex-grow property to display equal, but flexible widths for all flex items."

But why is the space of the container redistributed when the size of the flex items is less than the value you assigned the flex-basis property?

Comment: @llltellyoulater Stackoverflow is not a learning platform please search this issue on google. Although below are the link by which you can solve your problem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Comment: ok @HardenRahul. But i dont think its explained well enough there thats why i came on here looking for help.

Comment: Illtellyoulater I Stackoverflow is a teaching platform where you just put your problem & get it sorted. It's not a teaching platform where someone comes you guide you.